# AWS give user access to only elastic beanstalk instances and storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

How to give access to a IAM user to only access resources created by Elastic bean, i.e. The S3 bucket and the EC2 instances. The user should not be able to access any other S3 bucket or EC2 instance not created with Elastic Beanstalk. 
The same policy should apply to EC2 instances created automatically via the Auto Scaling policy.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the "tags" approach. You can set elasticbeanstalk and autoscaling launch configuration to create instances with a predefined "tags" . And you can allow users to see only this tags.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {"StringEquals": {"ec2:ResourceTag/department": "dev"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

There could be better approaches, we should wait and see other responses.

best,

Comment: Thanks for the info, dont seem to be any other responses. Do you know from where I can learn to write the above scripts ?